# How can we delete one value only from the array of localStorage?

Tags: javascript, jquery, local-storage

For example LocalStorage with  Key: watchlist, value: [5632, 5421, 2964]

```
const dataId = 5421;
const existingUnWatchlist = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('watchlist') || '[]');

if (existingUnWatchlist.includes(dataId)) {

        let index = existingUnWatchlist.indexOf(dataId);
        existingUnWatchlist.splice(index, dataId);
        localStorage.setItem('watchlist', JSON.stringify(existingUnWatchlist));

}
```

Those above code delete array [1 : 5421] and whole rest part of all array below. I just want to delete a single array value can it be possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change

```
 existingUnWatchlist.splice(index, dataId);
```

to

```
 existingUnWatchlist.splice(index, 1);
```

The second argument of `splice` is how many elements to delete, anything after the second argument will be added

```
let arrDeletedItems = array.splice(start[, deleteCount[, item1[, item2[, ...]]]])
```

Comment: Thanks, Its work by changing : 'existingUnWatchlist.splice(index, 1);'